# Spring MVC - passed http request argument not match the same String value, why?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, encoding

I'm passing email parameter with value "adrian@domain.com in that way:

```
.../confirmation?email="adrian@domain.com"
```

That request is handled by following Controlerr's method which assign parameter to ModelAtrribute added to confirm.jsp view:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/confirmation")
    public String accessConfirmationForm(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email, Model model)
    {
        ConfirmationCode confCode = new ConfirmationCode();
        confCode.setEmail(email);
        model.addAttribute("confCode", confCode);

        return "confirm";
    }
```

That's code from confirm.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Confirmation</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form modelAttribute="confCode" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/confirm" method="get">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Confirmation code for email ${confCode.email}:</td>
<td><form:input path="confirmationCode" /></td>
<td><font color="red"><form:errors path="confirmationCode"></form:errors></font></td>
<td><form:hidden path="email" value= "${confCode.email}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Confirm"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

After submitting the form request is reirected to following controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/confirm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String confirmUser(
//          @RequestParam(value = "email", required=false) String email,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "confCode") ConfirmationCode confCode, BindingResult result,
            Model model) {...}
```

Problem is that email variable of confCode attribute in this stage is not equal to manualy type String "adrian@domain.com", but when printing email variable on console i can see excatly the same String "adrian@domain.com" without any trailing spaces.

It causes that email variable is not applicable when i'm trying to get by email an entity in DAO implementation class:

```
//it causes null reference 
Emails mail = entityManager.find(Emails.class, email);

//it returns proper Entity
Emails mail = entityManager.find(Emails.class, "adrian@domain.com");
```

I think the reason why these two String aren't equal could be encoding, maybe? Encoding in my db is latin-1 (iso 8859-1)?

How to solve this problem?

Why both String aren't equal to each other?

Comment: that constructor for String isn't even defined.

Comment: It doesn't work. Still the same problem. Maybe it's not about encoding. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.../confirmation?email="adrian@domain.com"

I think the param value shouldn't have double quote